# How to start a server monitoring perl script and execute the client side code in the same script

Tags: perl, bash

I need to launch a server script which will not exit. and after the server is ready I need to start the client code to run some automated tests.

1. tried, not work, the server process is not in the background and the client code cannot be executed.
   system ($server &)
2. is it possible to use Parallel::ForkManager to handle this, how? all the examples are repetitive tasks, while my case is server and client.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel::ForkManager isn't really designed for this; there are various other distributions for supporting what a server needs to do; [Daemon::Daemonize](http://p3rl.org/Daemon%3a%3aDaemonize) looks like it does the fewest other things besides just running your designated server code in the background.

Comment: thanks for the answer. it sounds the solution. another question about the kill process, how can I kill the daemon process at the end? using the write_pidfile and delete_pidfile methods? it doesn't work at the first try.

Comment: those do nothing to the process; they just record the pid in a file (typically used to see from other processes if the server is running or to kill it).  From perl, you can do `kill 'TERM', $pid` to kill a process.

Comment: A strange thing I noticed during test. I can set pid in the daemon subroutine and read the value, but the value you get by ps -x | grep "e.g. key" is always incremented by 1. I get $pid= 24901, and the grep value is 24902. I need to kill the 24902 to end the daemon process.